# How do I change the time interval displayed in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar's week view, the time of day is listed down the left side of the panel.  Each hour is divided into two blocks.

Is there a way to change this to "squeeze" down the time so it only displays 1 block per hour?  Or perhaps expand this to have 4 blocks in an hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like your need to increase the number of blocks in the daily view is a popular, yet unexecuted, feature request:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=2bbf77cd9466983c&hl=en

Comment: Beautiful, that helps.  I'll go add my voice to the crowd.